# html accessing iframe elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

In a very simple setup, I do get wrong output.
File MyFrame.HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Frame</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a><br />
    <a href="https://www.bingle.com">Bingle</a><br />
  </body>
</html>
```

File MyPage.HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="MyFrame.HTML" loading="eager" id="MyFrame123"></iframe>
  </body>
  <script>
    //does this script run after MyFrame is loaded?
    setTimeout(function () {
      var frmDoc = document.getElementById("MyFrame123");
      if (frmDoc != null) {
        var n = frmDoc.getElementsByTagName("A").length;
        console.log(n); //n==0, why?
      } else console.log("no frmDoc");
    }, 5000);
  </script>
</html>
```

console output shows 0 after 5sec delay, why ???

Comment: tested on the latest version of Chrome from Google.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```js
const frmDoc = document.getElementById("MyFrame123");
const iframeDoc = frmDoc.contentDocument || frmDoc.contentWindow.document;
console.log('innerDoc', iframeDoc)
var n = iframeDoc.getElementsByTagName("A").length;
console.log('n', n.length);
```

With `contentDocument` you can get the "document" inside the iframe, which you can could then query to get your `<a>` tags inside the iFrame.

But this will only work if the iframe is on the same domain as your website!

You can read more about it here:

- contentDocument: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument
- contentWindow: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow
- Same origin policy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: thanks, Boguz. So, my understanding is that even when both of my files reside in the same directory, they are still treated as being of different **origin**, and thus s.c. Cross-Origin restrictions apply. Now, how do you specify the **origin** in HTML document? I guess it's in the META tag, please assist: I've got to tell the browser my files have the **same origin**. TIA.